# SceneKit, CIFilter. CICategoryBlur filters nothing visible

Tags: swift, scenekit, cifilter

I'm trying to blur a node or create a blur effect in SceneKit.

```
    let ship = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("ship", recursively: true)!

    var ciFilters = [CIFilter]()
    ciFilters.append(CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur", withInputParameters: [kCIInputRadiusKey: 30])!)

    ship.filters = ciFilters
```

Results in:

[image: CIGaussianBlur]

Which, I thought ok maybe I'm using the CIFilter incorrectly. However CIHalftone works fine:

```
        ciFilters.append(CIFilter(name: "CICMYKHalftone", withInputParameters: ["inputWidth": 20])!)
```

[image: ciFilters.append(CIFilter(name: "CICMYKHalftone", withInputParameters: ["inputWidth": 20])!)]

I've also tried with CIZoomBlur also doesn't work, however 
CIPixellate does.

Am I missing something fundamental here?

Update: I have tried everything in CICategoryBlur and can't get any of them to work, however every other CICategory item i've tried I could get to work.

Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, I've had little success with the CI filters and SceneKit. I'm of the opinion they are broken, the ones I did get working hit the frame rate so it would have been hard to include them anyway.

Comment: Did you work anything out as an alternative? I'm trying to cheat a motion blur effect without resorting to shaders.

Comment: I used shaders, and the solution I came to was a bit more involved than I'd like. The end effect I was after is the [glow around the bullets you see here](https://twitter.com/lachlanhurst/status/671651858746707968). To do this I use Metal to render the scene to a `MTLTexture` from above using a point for each bullet, I then feed this through the Metal performance shader based Gaussian blur filter and use this texture as the diffuse material property for the water. Not sure this is much help to you however.

Comment: Interesting! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279833/cifilter-on-scnnode-only-works-in-simulator reports CIPixellate doesn't work on device. Please file a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com, with your project, and maybe they'll take a look at it.

Comment: CIFilter are not supported by SceneKit's Metal renderer. When running on a device, SceneKit uses Metal by default on iOS9. So if you need CIFilter you have to explicitly request a GL renderer (suing IB or programmatically).