# CIFilter on SCNNode only works in Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

Having a bit of a head-scratcher with the new filter features in SceneKit with iOS9.  To simplify the case as much as possible, if I add the line:

```
ship.filters = [CIFilter(name: "CIPixellate", withInputParameters: [kCIInputScaleKey: 30])!]
```

To the default SceneKit project, build and run for simulator, the ship pixellates as expected.  If I build and run the same project on-device, the ship disappears.  I've tried various permutations, multiple devices, and even several SceneKit demonstrations on blog postings, and they all have the same issue.  I'm just not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: This seems worthy of filing a Radar at https://bugreport.apple.com. Please post the bug number so we can dupe it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34210293/scenekit-cifilter-cicategoryblur-filters-nothing-visible reports similar trouble, but with a different CIFilter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CIFilter are not supported by SceneKit when using Metal (which is the default on the device). See documentation of SCNNode / filters.

If you need CIFilter you have to explicitly request a GL based renderer (using InterfaceBuilder or SCNView's "renderingAPI" property).

Comment: Is there a reason why Metal doesn't support CIFilter rendering, or is it just not supported **yet**?