# How to make a SCNNode glow?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, tvos

I'm trying to make my SCNNode which is a sphere to glow like this picture of our planet:
[image]

I tried creating another node and applying a CIFilter with no luck:

```
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")!
filter.setDefaults()
filter.setValue(1, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
let atmosphere=SCNSphere(radius: 21)
atmosphere.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents=UIColor.blueColor()
let atmosphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: atmosphere)  
atmosphereNode.filters=[filter]
```

From what I could research this is due to Metal not supporting CIFilter but using OpenGL might work but I don't know how to change my project to OpenGL.

Comment: Bah, my dupehammer obliterated a possibly useful link to other not-quite-duplicate questions: [SceneKit, CIFilter. CICategoryBlur filters nothing visible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34210293/957768) and [CIFilter on SCNNode only works in Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34279833/957768).

Comment: Also note that for something as simple as a fuzzy circular halo behind a sphere, a realtime blur shader is probably not very good in terms of visual bang for your performance-cost buck — see the duplicate question for some strategies to get that done without CIFilters. (Do file bugs if you find CIFilter not working regardless.)

Comment: @rickster thanks, will try your suggestion